# How to do numerical value comparison in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, comparison, case, teradata

The goal is to use case when to create multiple data ranges in Teradata SQL

my code in Teradata SQL is:

```
select 
case when a <= 5 then b 
     when (5 < a < 6) then c 
     else 0 end 
from datadate
```

column a contains numbers such as 1,2,3

The error sign shows at the first < as SQL is expecting one of: 'at'...'day', 'hour'

How to execute numerical comparison in Teradata SQL? when I try to use comparison symbols such as <, >, <=, Teradata SQL always assumes I am comparing time/date.

Comment: What is column a data type ?

Comment: column data are numbers such as 1,3,5

Comment: No Need to use single quote for then stmt ?
```case when a <= 5 then 'b' 
     when (5 < a < 6) then 'c' 
     else '0' end as cond ```

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work this way. still got the same error code

Comment: Please update your question with the ddl for the datadate table and also add the full error message

Comment: And show actual sample data, what you're trying to do, etc.  Based on your error message, you are dealing with timestamps, but your post shows integers.  Finally, if you are dealing with integers, `5 < a < 6` is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only compare two operands:

```
case when a <= 5 then b 
     when 5 < a AND a < 6 then c 
     else 0 
end
```

But as CASE returns the *first* WHEN calculated TRUE:

```
case when a <= 5 then b 
     when a < 6 then c -- all values <= 5 are already returned by the 1st when
     else 0 
end
```